# How to handle close RadioButtonDialog

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have this RadioPickerDialog:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_radio_buttons, null);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_radio_title);
    tvTitle.setText(title);
    builder.setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok, (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) (dialog, which) -> {
                listener.onPickerConfirmClicked(getSelectedIndex());
                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) (dialog, which) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        T item = items.get(i);
        radioButton.setText(item.toString());
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }

    RadioButton buttonCheckedByDefault = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(defItemNum);
    buttonCheckedByDefault.setChecked(true);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Dialog call:

```
UiUtils.showRadioButtonPickerDialog(this, reasonList, getString(R.string.workshift_pause), 0, new RadioButtonPickerDialog.PickerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPickerConfirmClicked(int selectedIndex) {
                    presenter.setPause(reasonList.get(selectedIndex), true);
                }
            }
    );
```

I want to handle not clicked event (click in not dialog or click on cancel button). How i can do it?

Comment: *click in not dialog* I suppose this means the `dialog.setOnDismissListener()` and cancel button is on your `.setNegativeButton()`

Comment: @Tepits it's working only in DialogFragment, i have Dialog. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution:

```
....
//When clicked negativeButton
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
    dialog.dismiss();
}

//when clicked not in the dialog box
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add listener to close event, like via `setOnDismissListener()` method. It's also a good idea to call some kind of outer-class level-ed callback inside this method, to delegate this work to caller (fragment/activity, which showed this dialog) and that way you will always have reference to currently shown fragment, in case you may/need show more than one.

Comment: It's not DialogFragment.

Comment: Take a look at this then, it has all you will even need https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs